# Keyboard not working until boot sequence is finished

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, keys

Ever since the most recent updates of 25 November 2019 on 19.10 my keyboard isn't recognized from the boot screen until the after grub is done.

As such I can't access the BIOS or other operating systems without using a PCI  keyboard, and even that's spotty at best.

Comment: stupid question but is your keyboard wireless? what does the logs tell you.

Comment: No, USB. I've tried several other keyboards except wireless.

Comment: This is turning into a real puzzle. I can't read the contents of an ereader, which has never happened before. It doesn't show in lsusb either. Other USB devices are working normally.